# How to get username in joomla 3.2

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I had built an external application which retrieve Joomla User Information and I user the code as below :

```
session_start();
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '../' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'../includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'../includes/framework.php' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$myuserid = $user->username;
$_SESSION["myid"] = "$myuserid";
$myid = $_SESSION["myid"];
echo 'User name: ' . $myid . '<br />';
```

However, the output of $myid is not displayed in the site. It just displayed as :

```
User name :
```

The displayed should be :

```
User name : admin
```

Is there's a problem with my coding?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If this is external code, where are you logging in to the Joomla! system?

Comment: Dear Mike,it's an external system that called mysession.php and will be include in the other page called index.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [joomla.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

I think the framework not loaded correctly on the external page.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo '<pre/>';
print_r($user);
```

Do not use `session_start()` for Joomla If you need to use session try Joomla session library.

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('variable','your_value');
echo $session->get('variable');
```

In your case the logged in admin name will be.

```
echo $user->username;
```

Hope it works..

Comment: Dear Jobin, thanks but sorry it's doesn't work. :( Let me explain in detail. The extension file above called mysession.php and will be called in wrapper file in joomla called index.php In the index.php page, i put                                              <?php
    // Include config
    include('../php/config.php');
    include('../php/mysession.php');

    echo 'User name: ' . $myid . '<br />';

?>
If I log in as admin, then the output for index.php page should be User name : admin

Comment: @KokoroSan There are two things this external file that you are using inside Joomla frame work like including this file inside Joomla template index.php or part of Joomla installation file then no need of loading frame work to the page. Another thing is the path to this file is not a matter, the main thing you have to consider is the path to Joomla installtion `define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) )` here set the path to Joomla installation.

Comment: Dear Jobin, thanks for the explanation. I'd repair some coding and this is the output when i run the mysession.php file itself.     JUser Object
(
    [isRoot:protected] => 
    [id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [username] => 
    [email] => 
    [password] => 
    [password_clear] => 
    [block] => 
    [sendEmail] => 0
    [registerDate] => 
    [lastvisitDate] => 
    [activation] => 
    [params] => 
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )
I feel confused

Comment: @KokoroSan did you logged in the site ? bcoz all are empty!

Comment: Dear Jobin, Oh man... I forgot to log in... ^___^ no wonder... ok next step..how do I called the username and displayed it in my index.php as User name : admin                                  JUser Object
(
    [isRoot:protected] => 
    [id] => 709
    [name] => administrator
    [username] => admin
    [email] => admin@yahoo.com

Comment: So your admin name will be, `echo $user->username` do not use normal session variable with Joomla always use Joomla native libraries. :)  you can accept as an answer it will help others

Comment: Dear Jobin, thank you so much.. it's work!!! I owe you.. ^__^ sorry again for bothering you so much.. ^___^