# Joomla user insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I've made a form and would like the data inserted into my database to attache to the user, who's logged in at my website. 
I've used this form:

```
<form action="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=41" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="username">

<input type="radio" name="k1" id="k1" value="1">1<input type="radio" name="k1" value="X">X<input type="radio" name="k1" value="2">2<br />

<input type="text" name="k1r" id="k1r">

<div>

<p style="float:left; width:14%; margin-right:2%; background:#eee; color:black; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px"><input type="submit" value="Add Records"></p>

</div>

</form>
```

Ant the 'action' would get this code:

```
// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Escape user inputs for security

$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

$k1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['k1']);
$k1r = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['k1r']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO kampbs(username, k1, k1r) VALUES('$user', '$k1', '$k1r')";

if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
}


// Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The form-data is inserted as it should, but in the 'Username' field in the database it says 'JUser'. What should I do to get the Logged-in username (should've been the username 'DJ').

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO kampbs(username, k1, k1r) VALUES('$user', '$k1', '$k1r')";` in this you should use `$username` instead of `$user`, coz you are storing username value in this i.e `$username`.

Comment: @Bhaskar Wow, stupid me :) But when I do that, the 'username' field in mysql is empty?

Comment: another point, if you are retrieving username value from session, why are you using hidden field?

Comment: can you do one thing? `echo $sql = "INSERT INTO kampbs(username, k1, k1r) VALUES('$user', '$k1', '$k1r')";`  and post here

Comment: one more thing, did you start session in the beginning of the page? I mean `session_start();`

Comment: @Bhaskar Well, I have no idea how I should attache the username, so I just thought of a hidden field :D But please correct me.. I didn't use `session_start();` I just found the `$_SESSION['username']` part on google.

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what you mean, but if i use `echo` in the form, it echo: INSERT INTO kampbs(username, k1, k1r) VALUES('JUser', '', '')

Comment: by checking echo statements, seems your username not stored in session.

Comment: @Bhaskar Oh, so how do I do that? Or can I retrieve it somewhere else? I'm using Joomla btw.

Comment: do one thing, add this line `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>";` before `$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);`

Comment: but in joomla there is another way, check this - https://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/how-to-use-sessions-in-joomla/

Comment: I will look at it :) Will return afterwards..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get username in joomla 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645008/how-to-get-username-in-joomla-3-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did it now, thanks to @Bhaskar 's link. 
Joomla got it's own way to retrieve user-information:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

Afterwards I made the variable:

```
$username = $user->username;
```

And at last I just inserted it into the $sql like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO kampbs(username, k1, k1r) VALUES('$username', '$k1', '$k1r')";
```

That did it! :)